# Cannot drag the image once it dropped on to the target and dragging happens only once

Tags: html, jquery-ui, html5-canvas

Following is my code.

var canvas = document.getElementById("siddhiCanvas");

```
if (canvas.getContext) 
{

    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        //Modify the value of x & y and see the effect
        ctx.scale(2, 2);
        for (i = 0; i < 1000; i += 10) {
            ctx.moveTo(0, i);
            ctx.strokeStyle = "#D8D8D8";
            ctx.lineTo(canvas.width, i);
            ctx.stroke();

        }
        for (i = 0; i < 1000; i += 10) {
            ctx.moveTo(i, 0);
            ctx.strokeStyle = "#D8D8D8";
            ctx.lineTo(i, canvas.height);
            ctx.stroke();
        }

    }

    canvas.style.border = "black 1px solid"; 



     var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
     var $canvas=$("#siddhiCanvas");
     var canvasOffset=$canvas.offset();
     var offsetX=canvasOffset.left;
     var offsetY=canvasOffset.top;

     var image1=new Image();
     image1=document.getElementById("arrow").src;

     var $arrow=$("#arrow");
     var $canvas=$("#siddhiCanvas");


     $arrow.draggable( { 
            cursor: 'move',
            helper: 'clone'

          } );

     $arrow.data("image",image1); // key-value pair


     $canvas.droppable({
            drop:dragDrop,
     });


     function dragDrop(e,ui){
            var element=ui.draggable;
            var data=element.data("url");
            var x=parseInt(ui.offset.left-offsetX);
            var y=parseInt(ui.offset.top-offsetY);
            ctx.drawImage(element.data("image"),x-1,y);
        }
```

above code is within the document.onready function and the html part contains the canvas tag and the image.

As stated earlier i can drag only once and once a image dropped to the target i cannot further move it.. Also i drew strokes on the canvas and when i drag the image it goes to behind of those lines. Can anyone please help me on this...Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine jQueryUI and KineticJS to drag an image element from the toolbar to the Kinetic.Stage.

Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/LuZbV/

**Step#1** Use jQueryUI to make the image element in the toolbar draggable:

```
// make the toolbar image draggable

$house.draggable({
    helper:'clone',
});
```

**Step#2** Set the data payload on the draggable image element

```
// set the data payload

$house.data("url","house.png"); // key-value pair
$house.data("width","32"); // key-value pair
$house.data("height","32"); // key-value pair
$house.data("image",image1); // key-value pair
```

**Step#3** Make the Kinetic container div a dropzone

```
// make the Kinetic Container a dropzone

$stageContainer.droppable({
    drop:dragDrop,
});
```

**Step#4** When the user drops the draggable image element, create a Kinetic.Image using its data payload.

```
// hangle a drop into the Kinetic container
function dragDrop(e,ui){

    // get the drop point
    var x=parseInt(ui.offset.left-offsetX);
    var y=parseInt(ui.offset.top-offsetY);

    // get the drop payload (here the payload is the image)
    var element=ui.draggable;
    var data=element.data("url");
    var theImage=element.data("image");

    // create a new Kinetic.Image at the drop point
    // be sure to adjust for any border width (here border==1)
    var image = new Kinetic.Image({
        name:data,
        x:x,
        y:y,
        image:theImage,
        draggable: true
    });
    layer.add(image);
    layer.draw();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot again :) ,,, saved me lot of time ,,is it possible for me to get your personal email,,i can clarify stuff from you. i'm an undergraduate and do not have any experience with html5 ..Thnks again